# Power Query Custom Column with Numbers and Text

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to clean up my data by converting certain values to a number "2" but need to leave remaining data and data type as is.
I am using the following code with a custom column step in power query (excel) but it is giving me an error when returning a number.

`Number.From([Values_old]) otherwise if Text.Contains([Value_old],"not required",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or Text.Lower([Value_old]) = "N/A" or Text.Lower([Value_old]) ="NA" or [Value_old] = "100" or [Value_old] = 100 then 2 else [Value_old]`

See the result from the step:
[image]

I based my conditional column from the following comment I found in a forum: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/data-type-which-contains-both-test-and-number/m-p/55785/highlight/true#M22664

However, this seems to break my if then else condition as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.  you used the wrong column name, **Values_old** instead of **Value_old**

But your formula won't work then either since neither of these will ever work:

Text.Lower([Value_old]) = "N/A" or Text.Lower([Value_old]) ="NA"

because you are comparing something you just converted to lower case against an upper case

so you probably want below, which includes the **try** part you seem to have left out of your code

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each try Number.From([Value_old]) otherwise if Text.Contains([Value_old],"not required",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or Text.Lower([Value_old]) = "n/a" or Text.Lower([Value_old]) ="na" or [Value_old] = "100" or [Value_old] = 100 then 2 else [Value_old])
```